# Image size changed when enable the ZoomMode in uwp?

Tags: uwp, scrollviewer

I have the Scrollviewer and its content is an image. If I dynamically enable the ScrollBar visibility image height and width changed(Image stretched when enabling the visibility). How to do the zooming when dynamically enabling the visibility?

Comment: Not to clear what effect you want to achieve? Could you provide more details to clarify it?

Comment: If i disable the zoom mode ,the rendered image size is 850 x 546. If I enable the zoom mode and enable the scrollbar visibility means the image size changed into 950 x 603. Why it is changed? I don't want to change the image size.

Comment: Could you provide your code to help me see the effect? Do you set the Image `Stretch` property?

Comment: No, I didn't use the stretch property.                   <ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled" x:Name="sw" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
                      VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" MaxZoomFactor="10" 
                      MinZoomFactor="1">
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="Images\images_ICon2.jpg"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not given the `Image` a specific `Width` and `Height`, it will display on the room it can use.
As the `Image` control [Stretch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Image_Stretch) property introduction,

> A value of the [Stretch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.stretch) enumeration that specifies how the source image is rendered, if the Height and/or Width of the Image are not explicitly specified. The default value is **Uniform**.

The **Uniform** default value will have the effect that the content is resized to fit in the destination dimensions while it preserves its native aspect ratio.
When you dynamically enable the ScrollBar visibility, the display area will change, so the image will zoom.

You can try to assign the `Stretch` property of `Image` control as `None` so that the image will not zoom.

```
<Image Stretch="None" Source="Images\images_ICon2.jpg"/>
```

On other hand, you can also assign the `Image` a specific `Width` and `Height` property to make it not zoom.

```
 <Image Width="500" Height="500" Source="Images\images_ICon2.jpg"/>
```